# java generics - The method evaluate(T,T) in the type T is not applicable for the arguments (Comparable, Comparable<capture#11-of ?>)

Tags: java

I'm having a problem with a generic method since i upgrade my java version to 8.
The call is the following:

```
Operator o;
Comparable a;
Comparable<?> b;
boolean match = o.evaluate(a, b)
```

and the method

```
public enum Operator{

    public <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean evaluate(T value1, T value2) {

        if (value1 == null && value2 != null) {
            return false;
        }

        switch (this) {
        //some code here
        }     
    }
}
```

And the exception is: 
The method evaluate(T, T) in the type Operator is not applicable for the arguments (Comparable, Comparable)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`evaluate` expects to arguments that are known to be the same type, which can be compared to itself, but that's just not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Your generic method imposes two conditions:

1. That its return type extends the Comparable interface with respect to itself.
2. That its two parameters (and return type) are all of the same type.

However, you are passing two parameters which are not, strictly speaking, the same type. One of them is a raw Comparable object (whose base type is Object), and the other is a Comparable which is not raw, but has an unknown base type.

In reality you could assign an Integer to b, and that is not strictly compatible with a raw Comparable.

Using `a.compareTo(b)` would not result in a compile-time error, because `a` is a raw Comparable that will accept any Comparable object but will consider it to be Comparable and `b` can be cast to `Object`. That's how it works with raw types. You get only a warning, and a runtime error if the two objects do not match.

However, using `b.compareTo(a)` would result in a compile-time error, because b is known to have a base type, it's just not known what it is at the moment. So it's not known whether a `Comparable<Object>` can or cannot be cast to it.